# Using the & operator with charAt()

Tags: java

I want to check if a word has the letter 't' in it. If it doesn't then the integer `guessesLeft` will be subtracted by one. Here's my code, i'm getting an error on the first line.

```
if(word.charAt(1)!='t') & word.chatAt(2)!='t' & word.chatAt(3)!='t' & word.chatAt(4)!='t' & word.chatAt(5)!='t' & word.chatAt(6)!='t' & word.chatAt(7)!='t'{
        guessesLeft--;
```

Comment: Wrong placement of parenthesis just before the first &. And you should learn about loops, or contains, or regular expressions...

Comment: why dont just try String method .indexOf('t') != -1

Comment: Keep reading the String documentation.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you wanted `||` for logical OR, but even then it's `&&` for logical AND. `&` is bitwise AND.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check whether your `String` has `t` using [contains()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains-java.lang.CharSequence-)

```
 if(word.contains("t"))
```

Now take a look at what you are doing?

```
  if((word.charAt(1)!='t') & (word.charAt(2)!='t')) // remove rest of the logic
                                                    // and corrected syntax
```

You are checking using `&`(non-short circuit) `AND` here. You are checking whether each and every index not `t` not at least one `t`.

You can use your logic if you really want it in this way

```
  if((word.charAt(1)=='t') || (word.charAt(2)=='t')) // then it will consider 
                                                     //at least one  t
```

More things

What is short-circuit and what is non-short circuit boolean?

> short-circuit, meaning they don't evaluate the right hand side if it
>   that doesn't necessary. As an example if && left hand side is false no
>   need to evaluate right hand side one. In other way || if left is true
>   no need to evaluate right hand side one.
>
> non-short evaluvate both side always.

Comment: Simple, Short. No mess, No fuss. +1.

Comment: The link to the documentation is the most important part. Learn how to find solutions yourself.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with [`contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains-java.lang.CharSequence-)?

```
if (!"Word".contains("t")) {
    guessesLeft--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your if statement,

```
  if(word.charAt(1)!='t') //remove the bracket after 't'
```

Answer (score 0):

The `&` operator performs a bitwise AND operation. To use the logical AND operation, you have to use the `&&` operator.

Your code should look like this:

```
if(word.charAt(1)!='t' && word.chatAt(2)!='t' && word.chatAt(3)!='t' && word.chatAt(4)!='t' & word.chatAt(5)!='t' && word.chatAt(6)!='t' && word.chatAt(7)!='t'
   {
      guessesLeft--;
   }
```